# battery issues with 13.04

Tags: 13.04, battery

My battery has been strange since on 13.04.  I left my office with battery almost 100% charged, came home took a shower, and when I went to turn on my computer, the battery was dead.

The power statics say battery not present.

What can I do?

I would like to add this was working fine before today on 13.04

```
dustin@dustin:~$ dmesg | grep battery
[    2.848289] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
dustin@dustin:~$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info
cat: /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info: No such file or directory
dustin@dustin:~$
```

Comment: @Alvar I was using in my office when this happened.  I always used my battery to 0 and then full charged before unplugging.  I came back from class, (went home as above) the battery was charged, so I unplugged it.  It turned it on and it didn't respond.  Toshiba P755 series.  I bought the battery in March.  I don't know how to measure the volts.

Comment: How long did you charge the battery for?  Did you turn the machine off/sleep/hibernate?  Time it took for the battery to loose charge(drain)?

Comment: The battery charged for 8-10 hours.  It was asleep and the time it took me to walk home and take a shower so 30-40mins.

Comment: What OS did you have before, and how was the battery performance?  Was the purchased battery OEM, or after market?

Comment: @Mitch the battery has always been used on a Linux system: Xubuntu or Ubunut.  It is an after market battery designed for the computer.

Comment: How did you charge the battery when you got it?

Comment: @Mitch 24hours, used until dead, and charged to full 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since I had similar issues with no discernible answer from the Ubuntu community (official or otherwise) I raised a bounty on your question.

However since then, I did install *tlp* which has fixed my problem, it is an advanced power management tool for Linux. I start tlp in battery or ac mode depending on what my power source is.

I would strongly suggest giving it a go.

In the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw

sudo tlp ac start #or bat instead of ac
```

Comment: Is there any documentation to read about tlp?

Comment: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html and the man pages -  in terminal: man tlp

Comment: Do you have to start it every time or just when you first install it?

Comment: dustin, you may do it that way. If there is a way to sense what the power input is, you could always write a script to handle this. Personally I am writing a little program that allows me to toggle a button on my tool bar. I'll be happy to share it once I have time to do it.